# When to respond to "you" with "I" or "Me" from sentence context

Tags: grammar, programming

I'm writing a program that responds to sentences, but I'm running into an issue:

> **You write:** I like that `you` like me.
>
> **Program responds:** What do you think makes you like that `me` like you?
>
> **You write:** I like that `you` are my best friend.
>
> **Program responds:** I also like that `me` are your best friend .

In simple cases, switching 'you' to 'me' and me to 'you' works fine, but in this case it isn't grammatically correct.

**Under what circumstances should 'you' become 'I', and how can I tell from sentence context/wording?** Can you think of more cases in which you/me,my/your cant be interchanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the first two rows of the table on [pronoun case at OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/595/2/):

```
Pronouns as Subjects  Pronouns as Objects  Pronouns that show Possession
I                     me                   my (mine)
you                   you                  your (yours)
```

The second-person singular has the same form whether used as a subject (*you*) or an object (*you*). The first-person singular has different forms—*I* as subject and *me* as object.

In mathematical terms, the mapping of these first-person pronouns (*I*/*me*) to their second-person equivalents (*you*/*you*) is not one-to-one, so there's no inverse that maps the word *you* back to a single first-person pronoun.

To answer your question, there will be endless cases where *you* would need to be replaced with *I* (subjective case) and endless cases where *you* would need to be replaced with *me* (objective case). The context you need is the case of the pronoun *you*. I have no experience trying to algorithmically parse natural language at this level, but I gather it's not trivial.

Bear in mind that *you* can also be plural, so you may need to consider *we*/*us* (first-person plural) in addition to *I*/*me*.